# Java: finding union, intersection, diff, and xor of 2 sets each in 3 lines or less

Tags: java, methods, set, treeset

For a project, I'm required to find the union, intersection, diff, and xor of 2 sets. Each method can be no more than 3 lines of code. So far, I have working methods, but I can't for the life of me see how to condense the difference and xor methods down to 3 lines of code or less.  Here is what I have so far:

```
static TreeSet<String> union( TreeSet<String> set1, TreeSet<String> set2 )
{
    TreeSet<String> s1 = new TreeSet<String>(set1);
    s1.addAll(set2);
    return s1;
}

static TreeSet<String> inter( TreeSet<String> set1, TreeSet<String> set2 )
{
    TreeSet<String> s1 = new TreeSet<String>(set1);
     s1.retainAll(set2);
    return s1; 
}

static TreeSet<String> diff( TreeSet<String> set1, TreeSet<String> set2 )
{

    TreeSet<String> s1= new TreeSet<String>(inter(set1, set2));
    TreeSet<String> s2 = new TreeSet<String>(set1);
    s2.removeAll(s1);
    return s2; 
}

static TreeSet<String> xor( TreeSet<String> set1, TreeSet<String> set2 )
{
    TreeSet<String> s1 = new TreeSet<String>(union(set1,set2));
    TreeSet<String> s2 = new TreeSet<String>(inter(set1, set2));
    s1.removeAll(s2);
    return s1; 
}
```

I've been staring at this forever, and it's just not coming to me. Thanks in advance for your time. I know this is probably an easy fix that I'm just not seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save one line each, if you don't use one of the helper variables. Instead, write

```
s2.removeAll(new TreeSet<String>(inter(set1, set2)));
```

for your diff method, and

```
s1.removeAll(new TreeSet<String>(inter(set1, set2)));
```

for your xor method.

**EDIT:**

```
s2.removeAll(inter(set1, set2));
```

and

```
s1.removeAll(inter(set1, set2)));
```

works as well, since your `inter()` returns a TreeSet.

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you! I just modified the code and this worked perfectly. I'm always surprised by the fun little tricks you can use to cut down the number of lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
static TreeSet<String> xor( TreeSet<String> set1, TreeSet<String> set2 )
{
    TreeSet<String> s1 = new TreeSet<String>(union(set1,set2));
    s1.removeAll(new TreeSet<String>(inter(set1, set2)));
    return s1; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer! MaxMega answered first, but I appreciate the answer nonetheless.

Comment: @neonroses no worries